# How to access backend from frontend on another localhost port?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, localhost, port

We are making a web application where we have split up the frontend and backend into seperate projects. After setting up security with CAS we are unable to access the backend from frontend, getting `401 Unauthorized`. Frontend is running at `localhost:3000`, while the backend is running at `localhost:8080`.

We would like to allow port `3000` to access port `8080`, but we don't know how, any clues?

Comment: Do you have any CORS registry configurations? If so, please provide the code/configuration

Comment: Maybe [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on two separate projects for frontend and backend you need to write RESTAPIs. to access the backend instance you need to set up authentication, it might be CSRF or CORS.
Please have a look at the cors document from spring boot 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

it is for the csrf
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Front end : localhost:3000/yourfilename.html

**Front end** default port of xamp port is 80. So We re basically use 
localhost/yourfilename.html. But Here used 3000 port. so We should call port 
number with that url 

**Back end** : localhost:8080/apiurl
It is ordinary port of backend.
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code for the benefit of other readers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to communicate with two different projects you need to write RESTAPIs, since you are using different port numbers, for security purpose you need to enable cross origin. refer this https://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-rest-cors-integration-using-crossorigin-annotation-xml-filter-example

Answer (score 0):

I am using Nestjs as backend and following codes in main.ts file is enough to handle requests from frontend.
(Adjust the URLs as per yours)

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);


  // Configure CORS

  app.enableCors({

    origin: 'http://localhost:5173', // Allow requests from frontend

    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'], // Specify allowed HTTP methods

    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'], // Specify allowed headers
    preflightContinue: false,

 // Disable preflight requests

    optionsSuccessStatus: 204, // Return 204 for preflight requests

    credentials: true, // Allow sending cookies and authentication headers
  });


  await app.listen(3000);
}


bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

`401 Unauthorized` error means your frontend is indeed able to communicate with your backend but is not sending the necessary information to authenticate and authorize the request because of the security you setup. That's why you get a `401` error.

Make sure the frontend sends the requested information to authenticate the request or that the user has the proper authorization to access the requested resource.